# Oracle SQL - Get name from table based on group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `employee` and has columns as follows

`emp_id number
emp_name varchar(30)
salary float
dept_id number`

I want to get the output as any one name of employee within that department and employee count from each department. I tried the below, but didn't work well

`SELECT emp_name, count(*) FROM emp 
GROUP BY dept_id, emp_name;`

Expected output:

`emp_name, count(*)
abc, 4
def, 2
xyz, 10`

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: How important that name to be truly *random*?

Comment: What do you mean by "random"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  lets say 100 records are there in employee table, and assume 5 departments and for all department there are records present in employee table as well, when I do GROUP BY, my expected output will be on from 5 set of groups, from each group multiple employee name would have been matched. I want any name matched within that set of group and the number of employee in that group as output. So, end result will be  randomly matched name within that group, employee strength from each department.

Comment: @AkshayHegde I don't mind about the uniqueness of the employee name, just the match is enough and the same has to be displayed in query's output

Comment: From what you are describing, you just want "some" name, **any** name, from the group. You call it "random" but you don't really seem to care if it is random. So: `SELECT min(emp_name) as emp_name, count(*) as cnt FROM.....` This will select the first employee name (in alphabetical order) from each department - is that enough for your purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want just a basic "random employee" shown for each department.

```
  select emp_name, emp_count
    from (
        select emp_name, dept_id,
                 count(*) over (partition by dept_id) emp_count,
                 row_number() over (partition by dept_id 
                                   order by dbms_random.value )  rnum
          from employee
          )
  where rnum = 1
  /
```

This uses analytic function to calculate the counts, and then pick off 1 random row to display.

Comment: is this good enough to take for millions of records as we're using partition by ?

Comment: Should be ... we use analytics a lot on millions of row, no issues . .. you're best to test it in an environment setup for testing performance .. make sure it works as expected "for you"  ;)